# EksCtl : Update node-definitions via cluster config file not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-vpc, amazon-eks, eksctl

I am using `eksctl` to create our `EKS` cluster.

For the first run, it works out good, but if I want to upgrade the `cluster-config` later in the future, it's not working.

I have a `cluster-config` file with me, but any changes made to it are not reflect with `update`/`upgrade` command.

What am I missing?

Cluster.yaml :

```
apiVersion: eksctl.io/v1alpha5
kind: ClusterConfig

metadata: 
  name: supplier-service
  region: eu-central-1

vpc:
  subnets:
    public: 
      eu-central-1a: {id: subnet-1}
      eu-central-1b: {id: subnet-2}
      eu-central-1c: {id: subnet-2}

nodeGroups:
  - name: ng-1
    instanceType: t2.medium
    desiredCapacity: 3
    ssh: 
      allow: true
    securityGroups:
      withShared: true
      withLocal: true
      attachIDs: ['sg-1', 'sg-2']
    iam:
      withAddonPolicies:
        autoScaler: true
```

Now, if in the future, I would like to make change to instance.type or replicas, I have to destroy entire cluster and recreate...which becomes quite cumbersome.

How can I do in-place upgrades with clusters created by `EksCtl`? Thank you.

Comment: Would you please show logs of error?

Comment: @Yasen No error, it says configuration is up to date. :-) Changes are not parsed.

Answer (score 2):

I'm looking into the exact same issue as yours.

After a bunch of searches against the Internet, I found that it is not possible yet to in-place upgrade your existing node group in EKS.

First, `eksctl update` has become deprecated. When I executed `eksctl upgrade --help`, it gave a warning like this:

```
DEPRECATED: use 'upgrade cluster' instead. Upgrade control plane to the next version.
```

Second, as mentioned in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/weaveworks/eksctl/issues/3006#issuecomment-752903704) and [eksctl document](https://eksctl.io/usage/eks-managed-nodes/#upgrading-managed-nodegroups), up to now the `eksctl upgrade nodegroup` is used only for upgrading the **version** of **managed** node group.

So unfortunately, you'll have to create a new **node group** to apply your changes, migrate your workload/switch your traffic to new node group and decommission the old one. In your case, it's not necessary to nuke the entire **cluster** and recreate.

If you're seeking for seamless upgrade/migration with minimum/zero down time, I suggest you try [managed node group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/managed-node-groups.html), in which the graceful draining of workload seems promising:

```
Node updates and terminations gracefully drain nodes to ensure that your applications stay available.
```

Note: in your config file above, if you specify `nodeGroups` rather than `managedNodeGroups`, an unmanaged node group will be provisioned.

However, don't lose hope. An [active issue](https://github.com/weaveworks/eksctl/issues/2774) in [eksctl GitHub repository](https://github.com/weaveworks/eksctl) has been lodged to add `eksctl apply` option. At this stage it's not yet released. Would be really nice if this came true.

Comment: 2 years later still active - I've lost hope :)

Answer (score 1):

To upgrade the cluster using eksctl:

1. Upgrade the control plane version
2. Upgrade coredns, kube-proxy and aws-node
3. Upgrade the worker nodes

If you just want to update nodegroup and keep the same configuration, you can just change nodegroup names, e.g. append -v2 to the name. [0]

If you want to change the node group configuration 'instance type', you need to just create a new node group: `eksctl create nodegroup --config-file=dev-cluster.yaml` [1]

[0] https://eksctl.io/usage/cluster-upgrade/#updating-multiple-nodegroups-with-config-file

[1] https://eksctl.io/usage/managing-nodegroups/#creating-a-nodegroup-from-a-config-file